# magento rest join stockitems with products

Tags: rest, magento, join, product

I use Mgento rest to get Stock items and Products. I want to join results (i want to get product that contains sku & qty). Which key i must to use to join?

```
<item_id>576</item_id> = <entity_id>576</entity_id>
```

or

```
<product_id>576</product_id> =  <entity_id>576</entity_id>
```

?

stockitem:

```
 <data_item>
    <item_id>576</item_id>
    <product_id>576</product_id>
    <stock_id>1</stock_id>
    <qty>100500.0000</qty>
...
  </data_item>
```

product:

```
     <data_item>
        <entity_id>576</entity_id>
        <attribute_set_id>4</attribute_set_id>
        <type_id>simple</type_id>
        <sku>501cap00001</sku>
...
      </data_item>
```

Comment: The right way to join is on stockItem.ProductId equals product.EntityId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is too late

stockItem:product_id = product:entity_id